# Silverlight web content on Windows Phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Windows Phone 7 uses Silverlight as one of its "native" development APIs.  But does the Windows Phone 7 version of Internet Explorer support Silverlight as a plugin so you can view web-hosted Silverlight content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, no - this version of Windows Phone 7 does not support browsing to Silverlight content.

Comment: Thanks, Mike.  Do you know (or can you say) if this is on the feature roadmap or if there have been many requests for such a feature?

Comment: I dont think that they will ever support it. If even they do support it, they will limit it to very tiny set of libraries probably media elements. If they support this feature to complete silverlight, then it will beat the purpose of having Market Place and App approval.

Comment: If they do support Silverlight on the Browser - these won't be able to access the Phone API such as the devices or tasks directly like a Windows Phone 7 app can. They have mentioned this would be a like to have feature - but don't count on it - if it does come it will be a few versions away.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Answer (score 1):

The limitation here is plugin support in IE Mobile 7 on the Windows Phone 7 platform and is acknowledged by MS as the reason why Silverlight, Flash, etc are not supported "in browser".

Microsoft is on record stating that when IE supports plugins, Silverlight and other plugins will be available on WP7.